# What does this error "SEVERE: Server sent Vaadin 6 style updates for Connector...but this is not a Vaadin 6 Paintable" mean in Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I am learning Vaadin 7, I am reading the `Vaadin 7 CookBook`. Actually I am at chapter 4. I would like to ask if someone has ever encountered such a problem:

I get the following error in the browser console:

> SEVERE: Server sent Vaadin 6 style updates for
>   ChromaHashPasswordFieldConnector (3) but this is not a Vaadin 6
>   Paintable

[image]

when I render this UI:

```
public class ChromaHashUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = ChromaHashUI.class, widgetset = "com.example.chromahash.widget.Chapter_4___custom_widgets___creating_a_chroma_hash_password_fieldWidgetset")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layout);

        layout.addComponents(new ChromaHashPasswordField(), new ChromaHashPasswordField());
    }

}
```

The two `ChromaHashPasswordField` components are custom GWT based widgets, here is the code:

*ChromaHashPasswordField* server side component:

```
public class ChromaHashPasswordField extends com.vaadin.ui.PasswordField {

    public ChromaHashPasswordField() {
    }

    @Override
    public ChromaHashPasswordFieldState getState() {
        return (ChromaHashPasswordFieldState) super.getState();
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return super.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        getState().text = value;
    }
}
```

*ChromaHashPasswordFieldWidget* client side component:

```
public class ChromaHashPasswordFieldWidget extends Composite {

    public static final String CLASSNAME = "chromahashpasswordfield";

    private PasswordTextBox textBox = new PasswordTextBox();
    private HTML chromaHashStripes = new HTML();
    private HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
    private int numberStripes = 3;

    public ChromaHashPasswordFieldWidget() {
        initWidget(panel);
        setStyleName(CLASSNAME);
        panel.add(textBox);
        panel.add(chromaHashStripes);
    }

    private String[] getChromaHash(String text, int numberStripes) {
        String salt = "du467e4aSdfe";
        text += salt;
        String[] colors = new String[numberStripes];

        int hash;
        int part = text.length() / numberStripes;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberStripes; i++) {
            hash = text.substring(part * i, 
                                 (part * i) + part).hashCode();
            colors[i] = "#" + intToRGB(hash);
        }
        return colors;
    }

    public String intToRGB(int i) {
        String RGB = Integer.toHexString(((i >> 16) & 0xFF))
                   + Integer.toHexString(((i >> 8) & 0xFF))
                   + Integer.toHexString((i & 0xFF));
        while (RGB.length() < 6) {
            RGB += "0";
        }       
        return RGB;
    }

    public void updateChromaHashStripes() {
        String[] chromaHash = getChromaHash(getText(), numberStripes);
        int height = 18;
        int width = 6;

        String htmlStripes = "<div style=\"margin: 3px;\">";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberStripes; i++) {
            htmlStripes += "<div style=\"background-color: "+ chromaHash[i] + ";"
                                      + " float: left; height: "+ height + "px;"
                                      + " width: "+ width +"px;\">" 
                          +"</div>";
        }
        htmlStripes += "</div>";
        chromaHashStripes.setPixelSize(height * 2, width * numberStripes);
        chromaHashStripes.setHTML(htmlStripes);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textBox.getText();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textBox.setText(text);
    }

    public HandlerRegistration addKeyUpHandler(KeyUpHandler handler) {
        return textBox.addKeyUpHandler(handler);
    }

}
```

The *ChromaHashPasswordFieldState* component's shared state:

```
public class ChromaHashPasswordFieldState extends com.vaadin.shared.ui.textfield.AbstractTextFieldState {
    // initializer block, overrides AbstractTextFieldState's ones       
    {
        primaryStyleName = null;
    }

}
```

And the *ChromaHashPasswordFieldConnector* connector:

```
@Connect(ChromaHashPasswordField.class)
public class ChromaHashPasswordFieldConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ChromaHashPasswordFieldConnector() {
        getWidget().addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
            @Override
             public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
               getWidget().updateChromaHashStripes();
             }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Widget createWidget() {
        return GWT.create(ChromaHashPasswordFieldWidget.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ChromaHashPasswordFieldWidget getWidget() {
        return (ChromaHashPasswordFieldWidget) super.getWidget();
    }

    @Override
    public ChromaHashPasswordFieldState getState() {
        return (ChromaHashPasswordFieldState) super.getState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(StateChangeEvent stateChangeEvent) {
        super.onStateChanged(stateChangeEvent);
        final String text = getState().text;
        getWidget().setText(text);
        getWidget().updateChromaHashStripes();
    }

}
```

When I compile and run the project, everything works as expected as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

But there's that error I mentioned above in the console. Does it have to do with different Vaadin versions? Can I fix this error or is it something Vaadin/GWT related?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend on the server side the `PasswordField` class, which extends `AbstractTextField` and `AbstractTextField` implements the `com.vaadin.ui.LegacyComponent` interface. `LegacyComponent` makes easier to convert Vaadin components from Vaadin 6 to Vaadin 7 and most of the core components are converted that way.

When server-side class implements the `LegacyComponent` interface, the connector for that class must implement the `com.vaadin.client.Paintable` interface. You see the error message because, your connector doesn't implement the interface. In `Paintable.updateFromUIDL` you should handle changes from `LegacyComponent.paintContent`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how should I actually implement the `Paintable` interface? The book I am reading doesn't say anything about that. Is it mandatory or could I safely avoid its implementation?

Comment: And another thing. If `PasswordField` extends `AbstractTextField` which implements `LegacyComponent` and I extend `PasswordField`, my class automatically inherits the `Paintable` interface implementation made in `AbstractTextField/PasswordField`, so should't this be enough?

Comment: Let the connector just implement the Paintable interface:ChromaHashPasswordFieldConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector implements Paintable..

Comment: I had to realise that `Paintable` is implemented at connector side and not at server side, which means that my previous affirmation is invalid. Thank you Henri, it works!